# work with OAuth2 in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement a OAuth2 appcelerator connector for Studio to connect to a wordpress (WP has installed plugins REST API, OAuth2 server). And appcelerator download this module https://github.com/JiriChara/titanium-oauth2-client, but it is a version of 2012 which certainly has flaws. Unfortunately I could not make them work together.

I want to ask the community (Since it is the first time I am developing this type of connection between an app and a website in wordpress), if they have any solution please.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I think that since the oAuth protocol hasn't changed, you should still be able to use that library you linked to. I see that it hasn't been updated in a while - and maybe that's because there is nothing to update.

If you encounter specific problems using the library you can clone the source and try to fix (maybe even revive the project and push back to GIT).

Basically, oAuth is a set of HTTP calls - so you can write it on your own. But since a lot of the job was already made in that module I would try to get it working and push whatever fixes I can so others searching for the same thing can enjoy it as well.

Comment: OK ..... I tried it , recently with an app for android and I could not run . But thank you very much for your answer. If I had more conocimineto Oauth , I would like to contribute to this project .

Thank you very much

Comment: @AntonioMedel What didn't work? what errors did you get? maybe we can try fixing it together...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo.  It is an Appcelerator Titanium widget that was written to work with Azure oAuth2 but it would only take slight modifications to make it work with other oAuth2 systems.  I was successful doing this for a recent project.

https://github.com/grantges/co.grantges.azure.adal

Comment: OK thank you very much . Probare With This repository

Answer (score 0):

The first is that they can update the code (include to require) . I also try to take this module, but does not work .

regards